# Bounds for a continuous function given that f(0)=e and f(R)=(-2,-1)U[1,5)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let  $f:R→R$ be a function such that $f(R)$ is a subset of $(-2,-1) \cup [1,5)$ and $f(0)=e$. Can you give realistic bounds for $f$?

This is a question I got from a book and I didn't understand the question nicely. A solution to this will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take $M = 6$ then $| f(x) | \le M$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ .

Comment: but f(0)=e is not used in this case..there must be a further strong conclusion than this..

Comment: @Dishant $f(0)=e$ has no effect. The best upper bound for $f$ is $5$.

Comment: @Dishant The best you can say is $$1\le f(x)\lt5$$

Comment: Well, I wanted to mention one more thing in the description..f is continuous..so does that help in getting stronger conclusion?

Comment: No. It’s not getting stronger.